# How to change font and color of floating damage numbers? [World of Warcraft 1.13.3]

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

[image]

I would like to change the font of the floating text, as well as its color, depending on the school of magic which was damaged.

I can get the school of magic of the damage done in the event handler "COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED" by filtering out events in which "sourceGUID" is my character and the result of the "GetSchoolString" function. But how to apply this to existing floating text?

I reviewed the add-ons "NameplateSCT" and "MikScrollingBattleText", but as I understand it they draw their own text, and do not use the floating text of the game. Can the code "https://github.com/Gethe/wow-ui-source/blob/classic/FrameXML/CombatFeedback.lua" help me? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this function isn't [protected](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Category:World_of_Warcraft_API/Protected_Functions) (to prevent cheating), you could just overwrite the function.

```
CombatFeedback_OnCombatEvent = function(self, event, flags, amount, type)
  --copy paste the rest of the code here, and change it however you want
  -- in the code, r, g and b are used to set the colour

end
```